# How do I access an array/object contain a list of files staged for upload in the jquery file upload plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, file-upload

I have setup a form on a rails site that I am developing and I configured the jquery file upload plugin. The upload form works fine. Multiple files can be chosen and all the ajax upload functionality works fine.

The issue I am having is that I need to provide a way for the user to "unstage" files that they have chosen to upload. The way I have the plugin setup it allows the user to chose or drag and drop files, when the files are added to the form they are added to a staging area (see below). What I need to do is allow the user "unstage" or remove the files from the form.

Basically I need a way of accessing and removing the files referenced in the jquery file upload form.

I am using the basic jquery file upload plugin without all the optional scripts that come with jquery file upload. Here is a link to the jquery file upload repo: https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload

[image: screenshot]

Here is the JavaScript that configures the jquery file upload plugin (this code is wrapped in a document ready function):

```
// initalize and configure the jQuery File Uploader
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
  uploadTable: $('.file-upload-list'),
  downloadTable: $('#photo'),
  dropZone: dropZone,
  sequentialUploads: true,
  autoUpload: false,
  maxFileSize:10000000,
  dataType: 'text',

  ... some code removed

  // when the user drags a file into the upload area
  drop: function (e, data) {
    $('.file-upload-table').show();
    $.each(data.files, function (index, file) {
      $('.file-upload-list').append('<li>' + file.name + '<a href="" class="close cancel"></a></li>');
});
  autoResizeColorbox();
  },

  // when the user selects a file normally
  change: function (e, data) {
    $('.file-upload-table').show();
    $.each(data.files, function (index, file) {
      $('.file-upload-list').append('<li>' + file.name + '<a href="" class="close cancel"></a></li>');
});
  autoResizeColorbox();
  },

  ... some code removed
});
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which file upload plugin you are using? Can you give a link to it?

Comment: yes, I am using just the jquery.fileupload.js file from https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload

Comment: I see that their demo page is using template to render a file and there is cancel button which removes file from list. Maybe you can try to go that way. Also, there is some ui version which has a method called .destroy. It is used to remove separate files (destroy of not ui version will only remove whole file uploader)

Comment: Do you know where the ui version is? Is it in jquery.fileupload-ui.js?   I have that file included and it doesn't seem to be working.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and found the answer. If false is returned from submit callback, the corresponding file will not be uploaded.